# Forcing numpy version with numpy==1.16.6 does not work

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I have a Dockerfile where the following command is run:

```
RUN python3.7 -m pip install numpy==1.16.6    sklearn==0.0    scikit-image==0.17.2    scipy==1.1.0    opencv-python==4.2.0.34    jinja2==2.11.2    Pillow==7.2.0    xlsxwriter==1.3.2    absl-py==0.9.0    fastjsonschema==2.14.4    termcolor==1.1.0    pycocotools==2.0.1    seaborn==0.10.1    onnx==1.6.0    torch==1.7.0    future==0.18.2    tabulate==0.8.3    pycryptodome==3.8.2    python-dateutil==2.6.1    backports-abc==0.5    backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0    bleach==2.0.0    certifi==2017.7.27.1    configparser==3.5.0    decorator==4.1.2    entrypoints==0.2.3    enum34==1.1.6    html5lib==0.999999999    ipykernel==4.6.1    ipython==5.4.1    ipython-genutils==0.2.0    ipywidgets==6.0.0    jsonschema==2.6.0    jupyter==1.0.0    jupyter-client==5.1.0    jupyter-console==5.1.0    jupyter-core==4.3.0    MarkupSafe==1.0    mistune==0.7.4    nbconvert==5.2.1    nbformat==4.3.0    notebook==5.0.0    pandocfilters==1.4.1    pathlib2==2.3.0    pexpect==4.8.0    pickleshare==0.7.4    prompt-toolkit==1.0.15    ptyprocess==0.5.2    Pygments==2.2.0    qtconsole==4.3.0    simplegeneric==0.8.1    singledispatch==3.4.0.3    six==1.10.0    terminado==0.6    testpath==0.3.1    tornado==4.5.1    traitlets==4.3.2    wcwidth==0.1.7    webencodings==0.5.1    widgetsnbextension==2.0.0    matplotlib>=1.3.1    nose>=1.3.0    pandas>=0.12.0    protobuf>=2.5.0    Python-gflags>=2.0    pyyaml>=3.10    h5py==2.8.0    keras==2.2.4    google==3.0.0    tensorflow==1.15.0    tensorboard==1.15.0    markdown==3.0.1    onnxruntime==1.4.0
```

As you see the version of python is specified, as well as the version of numpy. However, in running this command I get the following error

```
...
        File "/tmp/easy_install-lstih2fl/numpy-1.22.3/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
          ],
      RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.8 required.
      [end of output]
```

Apparently pip attempts installing latest version of numpy despite being requested to  install specific one.
How is this possible?

Comment: One of the other libraries has numpy1.22 as a requirement? Is `sklearn==0.0` correct?

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, I guess that some dependency do this, but how come pip does not attempt to install compatible versions of these packages? Regarding sklearn. It seems that the list was assembled automatically by the author of the dockerfile, the proper package is scikit-learn. However, this package does not seem to cause the problem.

Comment: Can you post enough of the dockerfile so that it becomes a reproducible error?